# Why don't {align*} items start from the same row when inside multicols?

Tags: align, overleaf, multicol

I've used LaTeX with overleaf for couple hours now.

The problem is that the aligned items do not start from the same row (height). How can I have two or three columns that start from the same row?

I wrote this script:

```
lorem ipsum

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{align*}
1+1=2
\end{align*}
\break


\begin{align*}
1+1=2
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}
```

whitch produced this result:
[image]

I expect both 1+1=2 to be on the same height.

Comment: Why are you using `\break` here? The `multicol` manual mentions that `\columnbreak` can be used to break to the next column. Guess what happens then. Note for it to align properly use a blank line above and below `\columnbreak` to force the paragraph builder (or what it is to run)

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Some tutorial used \break and as I said I am very new to this.

Comment: Do you *need* `multicols`? That's a one line `align*`: `\begin{align*} 1+1&=2 & 1+1&=2 \end{align*}` Please, add a real world example, so we can help you in the actual problem you have.

Comment: Exactly which tutorial? It would be nice to know about which materials give bad adcise.